# Openshift always gives 503 error for Node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, openshift, server

I'm trying to setup my very first Node.js + express web app using Openshift's free service.

I installed node + npm and the openshift tools on my computer, and tried to run my app. On my local machine everything works fine, but after I push my project to Openshift site, it always gives the `'503 Service Unavailable'` error.

I tried to `rhc app restart -a firstapp` ,but it didn't solve the problem. I also checked the package.json and it is correct.

Here's my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs      = require('fs');
var parser  = require('body-parser');

//Setup ip adress and port
var ipaddress ;

function initIPAdress() {
    var adr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
    if (typeof adr === "undefined") {
            //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
            //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
            console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using localhost');
            adr = 'localhost';
    }

    ipaddress = adr;
}

var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/admin', function (req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html'); 
        res.send( fs.readFileSync('./index_admin.html') );
})

app.listen(port, ipaddress, function() {
        initIPAdress();//Call setup ip adress
        console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                        Date(Date.now() ), ipaddress, port);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that the IP address was set up incorrectly , after the `app.listen` method. So, I had to change my code as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs      = require('fs');
var parser  = require('body-parser');

//Setup ip adress and port
var ipaddress ;

function initIPAdress() {
    var adr = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP;
    if (typeof adr === "undefined") {
            //  Log errors on OpenShift but continue w/ 127.0.0.1 - this
            //  allows us to run/test the app locally.
            console.warn('No OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP var, using localhost');
            adr = 'localhost';
    }

    ipaddress = adr;
}

var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/admin', function (req, res) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html'); 
        res.send( fs.readFileSync('./index_admin.html') );
})

initIPAdress(); //Setup IP adress before app.listen()

app.listen(port, ipaddress, function() {
        console.log('%s: Node server started on %s:%d ...',
                        Date(Date.now() ), ipaddress, port);
});
```